# Why does jupyter notebook not see biopython?

Tags: python

[image]

I made sure Jupiter notebook and biopython are in the same environment. I even tried to install biopython in jupyter notebook. For some reason, jupyter just can't import biopython

Comment: Make sure you're running the notebook kernel with the same interpreter you're installing `biopython` to.

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, it looks like you re-ran the first cell, so that's important to mention since it's not in order. Plus, you can ignore the other imports for now (see [mre]).

Comment: Try using `%conda` instead of `!conda`. See [What is the difference between ! and % in Jupyter notebooks?](/q/45784499/4518341)

Comment: To tag on to wjandrea's last comment, you may also want to see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands that are best practice in current Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks wjandrea! It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `from Bio import SeqIO`.

https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. I had that at first